# Color pallete function display wrong color

Tags: reactjs

Inside a React Project I'm trying to create a constant for stacking all the color codes inside a .js.

The code is:

```js
export const colors = [
  {
    primary: "#ff1944",
    secondary: "#ff1612",
    white: "#fff",
    black: "#000",
  },
];
```

The problem is that if I set the value: colors.white to a makeStyle (Material UI) the color remains black.

This happen to with primary and secondary as well.

Comment: `colors` is an array. Get rid of the square brackets **OR** use the first element (`colors[0].white`) and it should work.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you! I was sure is something wrong on my end. Sorry for the bother tho and stay safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining the variable as an array that's why `colors.white` doesn't work, try this:

```
export const colors = 
  {
    primary: "#ff1944",
    secondary: "#ff1612",
    white: "#fff",
    black: "#000",
  }
```

and `colors.white` to get access to the color.

Or:

use `colors[0].white` to get access to the color.

Comment: I would upvote it but the feature is not unlocked yet. Thank you!